# How to compute $\int\frac{x^7}{\sin(x)} dx$ efficiently?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

How to compute $\int\frac{x^7}{\sin(x)} dx$ efficiently ?
We need $Polylog$ for this.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you need to efficiently evaluate the definite version of the integral? Where is efficiency in the analytical solution?

Comment: Efficients as in not too complicated or long.
Efficient as in not 7 substitutions and 10 partials used.

Comment: The most efficient way today is to ask wolfram

Comment: @Norbert Wolfram is pretty nasty -- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Bx%5E7%2FSin%5Bx%5D%5D

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a less nasty answer?
Maple, by the way, gives what appears to be the same answer.

Comment: A long answer does not always imply a long method.

Comment: OK then, the short method is to ask Wolfram or Maple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could substitute $w = e^{ix}$, obtaining $2 i \int \log(w)^7/(w^2-1)\ dw$.
Now
$$ 2 i \int \frac{w^p\ dw}{w^2-1} = -i{w}^{p+1}{\Phi} \left( {w}^{2},1,\frac{p+1}{2} \right)$$
(where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function)
so take the $7$'th derivative of this with respect to $p$ and evaluate at $p=0$.  Then substitute back $w = e^{ix}$.
According to Maple the result is 
$$
 -\frac{7}{2}\,{{\rm e}^{ix}} \left( \frac{2}{7}\,{x}^{7}{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}
^{2\,ix}},1,1/2 \right)  +i{x}^{6}{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,ix
}},2,1/2 \right) -3\,{x}^{5}{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,ix}},3,
1/2 \right) \right.\\  -\frac{15}{2}\,i{x}^{4}{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,ix}},4,1
/2 \right) +15\,{x}^{3}{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,ix}},5,1/2
 \right) +{\frac {45}{2}}\,i{x}^{2}{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,
ix}},6,1/2 \right)\\\left. -{\frac {45}{2}}\,x{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{
2\,ix}},7,1/2 \right) -{\frac {45}{4}}\,i{\Phi} \left( {
{\rm e}^{2\,ix}},8,1/2 \right)  \right) 
$$